# Merge request for two similar questions

Tags: discussion, support

Can we merge this question:

- [Two-year program or Two-years program?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83260/two-year-program-or-two-years-program)

With this question here:

- [Why is "letter" not plural in "two letter words"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123894/why-is-letter-not-plural-in-two-letter-words/123906#123906)

The first question has one upvote, and the second nine. The first has two  three-line answers. The second has four substantial, developed answers. The first had 1077 views over the whole year. The second has had more than that in one day.

It seems that more people will get to see more and better answers if the first question is merged with the second far more successful one. Can this be done please?

[Full disclosure of interest: I have an answer on the second question. But I still stand by my argument above!]

Comment: Merging is difficult to undo so we want to be very sure before we do it, so I'd like to let this meta discussion come to a consensus first.  But for the time being, what I've done is change it so the *older* one is marked as a duplicate, not the *newer* one, because the newer one has better answers.

Comment: @snailplane That would achieve a lot of the same things! Thanks.